# Android Google Maps button to search for specific service

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have created an application that implements Google Maps. I was wondering if instead of setting the location with Longitude and Latitude you could do it so that you can search for a specific word and it will bring up arrow pointers to a few locations close to your current location.

Ideally I would like it so that I can code a button, which once clicked, will search for that word (i.e "Shops" would then bring up shops close to the persons location).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) helpful to you